# Dataset for meaningless “Nearest Neighbor”?

Tags: algorithm, math, dataset, nearest-neighbor, dimensional-modeling

In the paper "[When Is 'Nearest Neighbor' Meaningful?](https://cis.temple.edu/~vasilis/Courses/CIS750/Papers/beyer99when_17.pdf)" we read that, "We show that under certain broad conditions (in terms of data and query distributions, or workload), as dimensionality increases, the distance to the nearest
neighbor approaches the distance to the farthest neighbor. In other words, the contrast in distances to different data points becomes nonexistent. The conditions
we have identified in which this happens are much broader than the independent and identically distributed (IID) dimensions assumption that other work
assumes."

My question is how I should generate a dataset that resembles this effect? I have created three points each with 1000 dimensions with random numbers ranging from 0-255 for each dimension but points create different distances and do not reproduce what is mentioned above. It seems changing dimensions (e.g. 10 or 100 or 1000 dimensions) and ranges (e.g. [0,1]) do not change anything. I still get different distances which should not be any problem for e.g. clustering algorithms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the paper is right. First, your test: One problem with your test may be that you are using too few points. I used 10000 point and below are my results (evenly distributed point in [0.0 ... 1.0] in all dimensions). For DIM=2, min/max differ almost by a factor of 1000, for DIM=1000, they only differ by a factor of 1.6, for DIM=10000 by 1.248 . So I'd say these results confirm the paper's hypothesis.

```
DIM/N = 2 / 10000
min/avg/max= 1.0150906548224441E-5 / 0.019347838262624064 / 0.9993862941797146    
DIM/N = 10 / 10000.0
min/avg/max= 0.011363500131326938 / 0.9806472676701363 / 1.628460468042207
DIM/N = 100 / 10000
min/avg/max= 0.7701271349716637 / 1.3380320375218808 / 2.1878136533925328
DIM/N = 1000 / 10000
min/avg/max= 2.581913326565635 / 3.2871335447262178 / 4.177669393187736
DIM/N = 10000 / 10000
min/avg/max= 8.704666143050158 / 9.70540814778645 / 10.85760200249862

DIM/N = 100000 / 1000 (N=1000!)
min/avg/max= 30.448610133282717 / 31.14936583713578 / 31.99082677476165
```

I guess the explanation is as follows: Lets take three randomly generated vectors, A, B and C. The total distance is based on the sum of the distances of each individual row of these vectors. The more dimensions the vectors have, the more the total sum of differences will approach a common average. In other word, it is highly unlikely that a vector C has in all elements a larger distance to A than another vector B has to A. With increasing dimensions, C and B will have increasingly similar distance to A (and to each other).

My test dataset was created as follow. The dataset is essentially a cube ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 in every dimension. The coordinates were created with uniform distribution in every dimension between 0.0 and 1.0. Example code (N=10000, DIM=[2..10000]):

```
public double[] generate(int N, int DIM) {
    double[] data = new double[N*DIM];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int pos = DIM*i;
        for (int d = 0; d < DIM; d++) {
            data[pos+d] = R.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Following the equation given at the bottom of the accepted answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253611), we get:

d=2     -> 98460

d=10    -> 142.3

d=100   -> 1.84

d=1,000  -> 0.618

d=10,000 -> 0.247

d=100,000 -> 0.0506  (using N=1000)

Comment: Hi please see [here](http://example.com) , the distance itself should get bigger but the relative distance gets smaller.

Comment: I think your link doesn't work. My results show that the distance gets bigger (as you say) and the difference in distance decreases. What do you mean by 'relative' distance?

Comment: My bad this is the true [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253344/generating-a-high-dimensional-dataset-where-nearest-neighbor-becomes-meaningless) . See the chosen answer and the comments.

Comment: As I understand 'relative distance', this is exactly what my experiments show, it decreases from 0.999999.. (DIM=2) to 0.6178.... (DIM=1000). I'll update the answer with a better description of dataset creation.

Comment: thanks for providing real code and an example, this is in accordance to my own experiments.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't heard of this before either, so  I am little defensive, since I [have seen that real and synthetic datasets in high dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09596) really do not support the claim of the paper in question.

As a result, what I would suggest, as a first, dirty, clumsy and maybe not good first attempt is to generate a sphere in a dimension of your choice (I [do it like like this](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/create-pointset-on-a-sphere-or-a-klein-bottle/)) and then place a query at the center of the sphere.

In that case, every point lies in the same distance with the query point, thus the Nearest Neighbor has a distance equal to the Farthest Neighbor.

This, of course, is independent from the dimension, but it's what came at a thought after looking at the figures of the paper. It should be enough to get you stared, but surely, better datasets may be generated, if any.

---

Edit about:

> distances for each point got bigger with more dimensions!!!!

this is expected, since the higher the dimensional space, the sparser the space is, thus the greater the distance is. Moreover, this is expected, if you think for example, the Euclidean distance, which gets grater as the dimensions grow.

Comment: I asked this question also in stats section [see](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253344/generating-a-high-dimensional-dataset-where-nearest-neighbor-becomes-meaningless) as I explained there, I also have used "multivariate normal distribution" for up to 1600 dimensions and made some experiments. This distribution is supposed to make spherical shapes, but not only I did not get this effect but what I have seen was the difference between min and max distances for each point got bigger with more dimensions!!!!

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. Hope this helps. BTW, if you found this answer helpful, please *accept* the answer. Notice that you cannot upvote, as I did so for your question, because of your low reputation.